# Simple form - Keep radio buttons checked when edit

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, simple-form

I have few radio buttons; the issue is that when I edit the instance, the radio buttons are not checked anymore (however they have been saved in db when I created it). I would like that the radio buttons the user previoulsy checked, to be still checked when edit.

**_form.html.slim**

```
      .cov-pick-row.w-row
        - @inspiration_images.each do |img|
          - next if img.image.path.nil?
          .w-col.w-col-2.w-col-small-4.w-col-tiny-6
            label
              INPUT[type="checkbox" name="cover[inspiration_image_ids][]" id='cover_inspiration_image_ids' value="#{img.id}" class="hidden"]
              .image-cov-pick
                = cl_image_tag(img.image.path, height: 190, class: 'img-to-pick',  data: { ix: "cover-pick" }).html_safe
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `checked: true` for which it should be check. Ex. assume you have `db` column `check_status` where you store `checked` value then use `checked: img.check_status`.

From your sample code as much as I understand that you are saving `image id` on `inspiration_image_ids` so use can use `inspiration_image_ids.include?(img.id)`

Answer (score -1):

Use `checked: [#your ids]`

Example :

```
create_table "mymodel", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "interest_ids", default: [], array: true
end

# _form

    <%= simple_form_for(@mymodel)  do |f| %>
    
    <%= f.input :interests_ids, 
         as: :check_boxes, # Display check_boxes
         collection: Interest.all, # Search into ids collection 
         value_method: :id,  # Save only the ids
         checked: @mymodel.interests_ids, # keep and check the old values 
         input_html: { multiple: true } 
    %>
   ...
```